# Почему dhcp client не получает ip от dhcp server на cumulus?

Tags: сервер, сеть, nvidia, dhcp

Пытаюсь разобраться с настройкой протокола DHCP уже очень много дней на это потратил. Вообще не понимаю что не так. Делаю все на Cumulus. Снизу скрины конфигураций. Сервер должен получить ip address. dhcpd.service active. Но почему-то сервер не получает просто ip. Не понимаю еще почему команды nv которые в документации не работают, пишешь пишешь, а куда оно идет никому не известно, в итоге всё руками написал, сервер запустился, а клиент не получает.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CMY3.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPJd7.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не получает сервер ip